# What is a general solution to allow the client to choose the concrete instance of a method output?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

What is the general solutions to allow the client to choose the concrete instance of a method output?

For example, in the [Lucene API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/overview-summary.html) the [search](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Collector%29) method receives and modifies the collector input parameter, but this is generally regarded as a bad practice:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

An alternative would be to provide a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) as input and have the search method return the instance created.

What else?

Comment: `...receives and modifies the collector input parameter, but this is generally regarded as a bad practice` - why so?

Answer (score 5):

Generics - quite obviously? In C# it might look like:

```
public class Searcher
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetResults<T>()
    {
        return new[] { default(T) };
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var searcher = new Searcher();
IEnumerable<string> results = searcher.GetResults<string>();
```

Comment: Instantiating a generic type is not supported everywhere, namely Java. And even if it was, each subtype might have it's own constructor, and the Searcher should know nothing about that.